# Html + Css: How to create a auto-resizing rotated background?

Tags: html, coding-style, css, rotation

image a complete black web page. On this web page is a 100% size white div that fills the whole page. I'd like to rotate this div by -7 degrees (or 7 degrees counter-clock wise). 
This will result in the black background being visible in triangles on the edges, just like you had placed a piece of paper on a desk and turned it a bit to the left.

Actually this can be done with some css and it's working quite well (except for IE).

The real problem now is:
I'd like to have a normal, non-rotated div element on top of that to display the content in, so that only the background is rotated.

Rotating a contained div counterwise doesn't work though, because through the two transformations the text will be blurry in all browsers.

How can I realize that?
Best would be a solution workiing in current Webkit browsers, FF3.5+ and IE7+. If only IE8+ I could live with that too.

Comment: I am no html-buff, but can't you have both divs on "top-level" with absolute positioning so that they overlap?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
#content {

 position: absolute;
 z-index: 500;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

#background {
//Your white DIV
}


<div id="background"></div>

<div id="content">
 Lorem ipsum
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:absolute;` on the background and `z-index` it to the back.
[Here is an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/vxNwY/1/)

Comment: Pretty good, but I need at least IE8 support, and that's not working there.

Comment: The filter for IE only rotates 90,180,and 270 degrees I believe. You could probably use images to create the black triangles and position each to a corner of the page.

Comment: With matrix transformation it would work with any degree, the problem is that the matrix tranformation will move the div aside. Images are no option because they need to change their size depending on the size of the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

You have to rotate it back... http://jsfiddle.net/gFCHE/
Not blurry at all on Chrome or ChromeOS. It shouldn't be anywhere else either.

Add `overflow:hidden` to `#crooked` for a cool effect with images.
This CSS will work to get you started but you'll need to tweak it to work as you want it.

```
<div id='wrap'>
    <div id='cooked'>
        <div id='straight'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


  #wrap{
    background:#000;
    height:100%;
}
#crooked{
    height:100%;
    color:#f00;
     -moz-transform: rotate(-7.0deg);  /* FF3.5+ */
       -o-transform: rotate(-7.0deg);  /* Opera 10.5 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-7.0deg);  /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
      -ms-transform: rotate(-7.0deg);  /* IE9 */
          transform: rotate(-7.0deg);  
          filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(/* IE6–IE9 */ 
                 M11=0.992546151641322, M12=0.12186934340514748, M21=-0.12186934340514748, M22=0.992546151641322, sizingMethod='auto expand');
           zoom: 1;
}
```

## wrap{

```
    background:#000;
    height:100%;
}
#crooked{
    height:100%;
    background:#fff;
     -moz-transform: rotate(-7.0deg);  /* FF3.5+ */
       -o-transform: rotate(-7.0deg);  /* Opera 10.5 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-7.0deg);  /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
      -ms-transform: rotate(-7.0deg);  /* IE9 */
          transform: rotate(-7.0deg);  
          filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(/* IE6–IE9 */ 
                 M11=0.992546151641322, M12=0.12186934340514748, M21=-0.12186934340514748, M22=0.992546151641322, sizingMethod='auto expand');
           zoom: 1;
}
#straight{
     -moz-transform: rotate(7.0deg);  /* FF3.5+ */
       -o-transform: rotate(7.0deg);  /* Opera 10.5 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(7.0deg);  /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
      -ms-transform: rotate(7.0deg);  /* IE9 */
          transform: rotate(7.0deg);  
         filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(/* IE6–IE9 */ 
                 M11=0.992546151641322, M12=-0.12186934340514748, M21=0.12186934340514748, M22=0.992546151641322, sizingMethod='auto expand');
           zoom: 1;
```

Comment: Nice approach, but the div is moved in IE. It's not overlapping with the browser window as it is correctly in the other browsers. How can I fix that?

Comment: Hmmm I see what you're saying. I got it fixed in IE, but that broke it in webkit. Hopefully this will help some. I'm home with my daughters at the moment but i'll come back to it in the evening if you don't figure it out. http://jsfiddle.net/J8EzP/